# How to combine two rows in one in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm selecting data from 2 tables in postgres in this way:

```
SELECT matches.id id, first_team_id T1, second_team_id T2, name 
FROM matches 
JOIN teams ON matches.first_team_id = teams.id 
UNION 
SELECT matches.id id, first_team_id T1, second_team_id T2, name 
FROM matches 
JOIN teams ON matches.second_team_id = teams.id
```

#### That's how my table looks now:

```
id  T1  T2  name
1   1   2   Team1
1   1   2   Team2
2   1   3   Team2
2   1   3   Team1
```

#### That's what i need

```
id  T1  T2  name1  name2
1   1   2   Team1  Team2
2   1   3   Team2  Team1
```

I need the easiest way to do it. I've seen some solutions in similar questions, but i didn't manage with them. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want with two joins:

```
select m.id, m.first_team_id, m.second_team_id, t1.name, t2.name
from matches m join
     teams t1
     on m.first_team_id = t1.id join
     teams t2
     on m.second_team_id = t2.id;
```